# Using a variable in a function with sql and sh script

Tags: postgresql, function, variables, plpgsql

I am developing a set of .sql scripts which will be called by a .sh script. In this .sh script, I use the command:

```
psql "connection parameters" -f ./myscript.sql -v var1 = "schema.table"
```

For the moment everything is well.

In my .sql script, I currently have this:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION myFunction (tarteenpion varchar) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARED
   MONTH_MM varchar: = to_char (current_timestamp, 'MM');
   YEAR_AAAA varchar: = to_char (current_timestamp, 'YYYY');
   YEAR_AA varchar: = to_char (current_timestamp, 'YY')
   cmd varchar: = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS' || tarteenpion || ';' ;
BEGIN
   execute cmd;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

--SELECT myFunction ('schema.table');
SELECT myFunction (: var1);
DROP FUNCTION myFunction (tarteenpion varchar);
```

My problem comes from the use of my external variable :var1
- If I directly write my value 'schema.table' with ', the function runs correctly. But I don't want that.

- If I write my variable :var1 WITHOUT the '  I have this error

> SELECT myFunction (: var1); => ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "schema"
>
> LINE 1: SELECT myFunction (schema.table);

So it is interpreted as not usable by the function.

- If I write my variable ':var1' WITH the '  I have this error

> SELECT myFunction (':var1'); => ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
>
> LINE 1: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS :var1

So it is not interpreted but used by the function.

Can you guide me to find a solution that has bothered me for a long time.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make `psql` quote the variable value with single quotes:

```
SELECT myFunction (:'var1');
```

That will be replaced to

```
SELECT myFunction ('schema.table');
```

Comment: You are my hero!!
It works perfectly. I never thought of that. I will try to put it all in place in my project :)
Thank you so much!!